# Clojure's disappearing reflection warnings

Tags: reflection, clojure, console

A simple reflection warning example:

```
lein repl
user=> (set! *warn-on-reflection* true)
true
user=> (eval '(fn [x] (.length x)))
Reflection warning, NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:16 - reference to field length can't be resolved.
#object[user$eval2009$fn__2010 0x487ba4b8 "user$eval2009$fn__2010@487ba4b8"]
```

I want to make this into a function. But where do reflection warnings go?

```
//clojure/compile.java 63
RT.errPrintWriter()
                .format("Reflection warning, %s:%d:%d - reference to field %s can't be resolved.\n",
                                SOURCE_PATH.deref(), line, column, fieldName);

//clojure/RT.java 269
public static PrintWriter errPrintWriter(){
    Writer w = (Writer) ERR.deref();

//clojure/RT.java 188
final static public Var ERR =
    Var.intern(CLOJURE_NS, Symbol.intern("*err*"),
               new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.err), true)).setDynamic();
```

Ok so they go to System.err. Lets capture it's output:

```
(def pipe-in (PipedInputStream.))
(def pipe-out (PipedOutputStream. pipe-in))
(System/setErr (PrintStream. pipe-out))

(defn reflection-check [fn-code]
  (binding [*warn-on-reflection* true]
    (let [x (eval fn-code)
          ;_ (.println (System/err) "foo") ; This correctly makes us return "foo".
          n (.available pipe-in)

          ^bytes b (make-array Byte/TYPE n)
          _ (.read pipe-in b)
          s (apply str (mapv char b))]
      s)))
```

However, calling it gives no warning, and no flushing seems to be useful:

```
(println "Reflection check:" (reflection-check '(fn [x] (.length x)))) ; no warning.
```

How can I extract the reflection warning?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem a while back and created some helper functions modelled on `with-out-str`.  Here is a solution to your problem:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test) )

(defn reflection-check
  [fn-code]
  (let [err-str (with-err-str
                  (binding [*warn-on-reflection* true]
                    (eval fn-code)))]
    (spyx err-str)))

(dotest
  (reflection-check (quote (fn [x] (.length x)))))
```

with result:

```
-------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.1    Java 14
-------------------------------

err-str => "Reflection warning, /tmp/form-init3884945788481466752.clj:12:36 
             - reference to field length can't be resolved.\n"
```

Note that `binding` and `let` forms can be in either order and still work.

Here is the source code:

```
 (defmacro with-err-str
   "Evaluates exprs in a context in which *err* is bound to a fresh
   StringWriter.  Returns the string created by any nested printing
   calls."
   [& body]
   `(let [s# (new java.io.StringWriter)]
      (binding [*err* s#]
        ~@body
        (str s#))))
```

If you need to capture the Java `System.err` stream, it is different:

```
 (defmacro with-system-err-str
   "Evaluates exprs in a context in which JVM System/err is bound to a fresh
   PrintStream.  Returns the string created by any nested printing calls."
   [& body]
   `(let [baos# (ByteArrayOutputStream.)
          ps#   (PrintStream. baos#)]
      (System/setErr ps#)
      ~@body
      (System/setErr System/err)
      (.close ps#)
      (.toString baos#)))
```

See [the docs here](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.212/api/tupelo.core#with-err-str).

There are 5 variants (plus `clojure.core/with-out-str`):

- `with-err-str`
- `with-system-out-str`
- `with-system-err-str`
- `discarding-system-out`
- `discarding-system-err`

Source code [is here](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/src/cljc/tupelo/core.cljc#L180).

Comment: I think @alan-thompson's "with-err-str" uses the technique described by @amalloy, to rebind `*err*`. I didn't downvote, but it was an annoyance to go hunt for the advertised library's source code to see whether it was a distinct answer.

Comment: It would help to put the code for with-err-str here and don't include spyx. Then mention these come from tupelo. The library may be useful but not all of us need it, or we have our own tools. with-err-str is under 10 lines of code. Then it would really be a simple cut-and-paste.

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly discovered how `*err*` is initialized, but since vars are rebindable this is no guarantee about its current value. The REPL often rebinds it to something else, e.g. a socket. If you want to redirect it yourself, you should simply rebind `*err*` to a Writer of your choosing.

Really I'm not sure your approach would work even if `*err*` were never rebound. The Clojure runtime has captured a pointer to the original value of System.err, and then you ask the Java runtime to use a new value for System.err. Clojure certainly won't know about this new value. Does the JRE maintain an extra level of indirection to allow it to do these swaps behind the scenes even for people who have already captured System.err? Maybe, but if so it's not documented.